# Generating curve from curvature

Tags: graph, curve

I am looking to be pointed in the right direction, if it exists.

Is there software that can generate a curve in the plane given the curvature at (x,y) as a function (x,y)?

For example. If a curve originating from (0,0) with the slope 0 had the curvature C(x,y)=x , it would "climb" up the y-axis in a shape resembling a sine curve.

Thank you.

Comment: Curvature alone does not uniquely define a curve. So, theoretically what you asked cannot be done without more assumptions.

Comment: @fang Knowing C(x,y), initial slope and initial coordinates should be enough. If C(x,y)=1, slope=0 and coordinates are (0,0), a circle with radius 1 centered around (0,-1) can be traced out.

Comment: @OP: The result is not unique. For your example, there will be two results in 2d case: a circle with radius 1 centered at (0, -1) or at (0, 1). If we are talking about 3d case, then the result is infinite.

Comment: @fang From what i understand, one set of initial conditions in the plane yeilds two solutions/curves. Can there be more than two solutions for one set of initial conditions?